# Facebook PHP SDK URL not allowed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to login with my FB-account on my website http://www.example.com/index.php. I have replaced the AppId && Secret. I have also added a website-platform in the settings where I've set the "Site URL" to http://www.example.com/

But when I do `$facebook->getUser()` it always returns 0. And when I insert the login-link with `$facebook->getLoginUrl()` and I click on the link it redirects me to

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=AppId...
```

On this page facebook tells me that my App-Settings don't allow the URL

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[facebook]` and `[login]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[facebook-login]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure this in your Developer Console on facebook.

It's under Settings> App Domains

note that if you just do "www.example.com" - then you will need to make sure that the API request is coming from "www.example.com" - and not "example.com"